# How can I align RadioButton and TextView horizontally?

Tags: android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

[See the image... If I don't Use the RelativeLayout the output is `TextView`
 is below `RadioButton`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXcCg.png)

If I use the following code to align `radioButton` and `TextView` horizontally, the `radioButton`s are not identified as a part of RadioGroup, which leads to multiple selections.

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3">

         <RelativeLayout  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/laptop_for_gaming"
                    android:text="@string/gaming" />
           <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/radioButton3"                       
                    android:text="@string/gaming_desp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/laptop_professional_use"                                                            
                    android:text="@string/business_use" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton4"                       
                    android:text="@string/business_use_desp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And if I don't use the RelativeLayout they are not align horizontally instead they are one below the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:orientation="horizontal" on your RadioGroup

Comment: Here the RadioButton's are getting aligned horizontally not the RadioButton and TextView...I've 3 to 4 lines of text to display.

Comment: if I simplify your code by removing RelativeLayouts, everything is aligned.

Comment: If I don't use the RelativeLayout they are not align horizontally instead they are one below the other. See the image I've attached in the question.

Comment: If I use the Relative or Linear Layout this is leading to multiple selection of RadioButtons..

Comment: Yes I just saw this... So maybe you will just have to handle this by code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your radiogroup adding `</RadioGroup>` after the RadioButtons :

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3">


        <RelativeLayout  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


         <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/laptop_for_gaming"
                    android:text="@string/gaming" />
           <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/radioButton3"                       
                    android:text="@string/gaming_desp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/laptop_professional_use"                                                            
                    android:text="@string/business_use" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton4"                       
                    android:text="@string/business_use_desp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: ,I've forgot close the RadioGroup in the question but actually I've closed in the code.